# How to make django forms change as user enters information

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to make a django form that allows users to make some selections and then, depending on what selections they make, shows them the rest of the options that make sense. Here's an example of the logic I'm thinking:

```
1. Users selects their gender (radio button)

[magic happens]

2(a). Male users select their clothing options - trousers, shorts, shirt, jacket
2(b). Female users select their clothing options - skirt, trousers, shorts, dress, shirt, jacket
```

So my big question here is how do I make the magic happen so 2(a) *or* 2(b) only shows after the selection in (1) has been made?

P.S. I have some code, but it doesn't really interact with the [magic] - should I include it or not?

Comment: If you don't want the view to reload upon selecting the gender, you will need some client-side code to hide or show those fields.

Comment: @AKX That is the sort of look I'm going for - is that do-able in django forms? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: It's technically doable, but with a single form, the validation code will end up being pretty hairy. You might consider a wizard view such as https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html (haven't tested it)

Comment: @AKX thanks I'll have a look at that and report back here!

Comment: using  django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html will end up in many pages if there are multiple nested things to select. Using client code like hard coded jquery would do better (in a single page).